# Adding multiple attachments to e-mail from disc by iteration

Tags: c#, loops

***UPDATE*** I tested this with Excel documents instead of PDFs,
and it worked. Why won't it work with PDFs??

I am trying to add X amount of attachments to an e-mail by iterating over a list of file path strings. Instead I get X attachments, but they're all copies of the same file. So the amount of attachments is correct, but their content is not.

This happens even though:

1. the PDF files are saved correctly on disk.
2. whilst debugging, the list of file paths is correct.
3. whilst debugging, file names and file paths are distinct.

I am using [FluentEmail](https://github.com/lukencode/FluentEmail) to send e-mails.
Also, I am building upon the following [example](https://developpaper.com/sample-code-of-sending-e-mail-by-using-fluent-email-in-net-core/) (see 'Multiple attachments' section).

I added `Debug.WriteLine(path)` just to check if I am able to correctly output the strings in the loop, which I were.

My method:

```
public async void SendInvoicesEmail() {

    try {

        using (SqlConnection con = new(ConnectionString.connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new("query text", con)) {

            con.Open();

            SmtpSender sender = new SmtpSender(() => new SmtpClient(host: "smtp.office365.com") {

                EnableSsl = true,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email", "password"),
                Port = 587
            });

            Email.DefaultSender = sender;
            IFluentEmail newEmail = Email
                .From("email")
                .To("email")
                .Subject("subject text")
                .Body("body text");

            var attachList = new List<FluentEmail.Core.Models.Attachment>();

            // SourcePathList contains all the file paths I need to reference.
            foreach (string path in SourcePathList) {

                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);

                var attachment = new FluentEmail.Core.Models.Attachment {

                    Data = File.OpenRead(path),
                    ContentType = "application/pdf",
                    Filename = $"{fileName}"
                };

                attachList.Add(attachment);
                Debug.WriteLine(path);
            }

            newEmail.Attach(attachList);
            SourcePathList.Clear();
            FluentEmail.Core.Models.SendResponse result = await newEmail.SendAsync();

            if (result.Successful) {

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }
}
```

I have tried:

1. Using `newEmail.AttachFromFilename`.
2. Using `newEmail.Send` instead of `.SendAsync`.
3. Iterating over array instead of list.
4. Changed my SMTP host.
5. Tried using `ContentType` for older PDFs (even though I have updated software): `"application/x-pdf"`.

But none of the above made any difference.

[image]

The three items present are distinct, yet only the last item is added as file in the 3 attachments. Does `ContentId` matter?

Comment: To see whether it's an issue with your code or perhaps the multiple attach method I'd create a foreach loop just attaching each file individually and see if that works. Also, out of interest when you say the same file gets attached multiple times, which file in the list is it (last one)?

Comment: @sr28 thanks for the tip! I did what you suggested, but the problem persisted:
`foreach (FluentEmail.Core.Models.Attachment attach in attachList) { newEmail.Attach(attach)); }`
And, It is the *last* file, yes, that is uploaded as attachment(s).

Comment: If that doesn't work and it's always the last file it sounds like it's overwriting them in some way.

Comment: Maybe think about adding an issue here: https://github.com/lukencode/FluentEmail/issues?page=1&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen

Comment: No response from the authors.
Anyone have any insight to provide? Tasty bounty up for grabs...
Answer provided does not work. Only for Excel. But if I try to attach PDFs, and populate list manually like he did in his example, the error described occurs. This also happens if I try other PDF files. And If I - like in my example - populate the list with a loop.

Comment: I tried a few times to reproduce your issue, but it worked every time for me. I sent the email through one of my Gmail accounts with three PDFs attached and all appropriately attached and sent. 

I would double check that your code sample above matches what you've been trying locally. 

Or if you're able to create a small reproduceable project that you could share, it could possibly help narrow down any issues. I'd be happy to put my working sample up somewhere if you'd like.

Comment: @TylerMcEntee that is very kind of you, I would happily accept your sample, wherever you prefer. I will also do as you suggest, creating a mini project to see if the issue carries through should be my next step. I got a feeling it's something really stupid...

Comment: @OleM Here's my repo with a minimal reproduceable sending of multiple distinct PDFs. The files are all included, all you need to do is follow the README and update some strings with your STMP auth credentials.

https://github.com/tmcentee/fluentmail-attachment-repro

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I think stream object is not getting refresh in loop and it is adding same file content for each attachment.

you should use your stream object in using statement as below</strike>

I am also using similar functionality on my web using `System.Net.Mail`

Earlier I have suggested an untested code, which had a bug. Now I have tested your code again and it's working as expected. here is complete method which I have run in a MVC controller.

```
public async void SendInvoicesEmail()
        {
            try
            {
                SmtpSender sender = new SmtpSender(() => new SmtpClient(host: "smtp.sendgrid.net")
                {

                    EnableSsl = true,
                    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password"),
                    Port = 587
                });

                Email.DefaultSender = sender;
                IFluentEmail newEmail = Email
                    .From("Admin@admin.com")
                    .To("user@user.com")
                    .Subject("I am feeling lucky")
                    .Body("This email is for stack overflow problem solution.");

                var attachList = new List<FluentEmail.Core.Models.Attachment>();
                // SourcePathList contains all the file path on my machine.
                var SourcePathList = new List<string>
                {
                    "C:\\Consolidate_09122021085902.xlsx",
                    "C:\\PaySlip_15022022075604.xlsx",
                    "C:\\RateCard_14022022104134.xlsx"
                };
                
                foreach (string path in SourcePathList)
                {

                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
                    var attachment = new FluentEmail.Core.Models.Attachment
                    {

                        Data = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path),
                        ContentType = "application/pdf",
                        Filename = $"{fileName}"
                    };

                    attachList.Add(attachment);
                    Debug.WriteLine(path);
                }

                newEmail.Attach(attachList);
                SourcePathList.Clear();
                FluentEmail.Core.Models.SendResponse result = await newEmail.SendAsync();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // write log file
            }
        }
```

Here is Email Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but implementing this gives me an exception: Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll, and "Sending mail failed". Any idea why?

Comment: @OleM You might need to update the smtp host in this example. Pankaj is using sendgrid while your example had Office365

Comment: Thank you for your revised answer, but as far as I can see, this code is identical to my original code. Which makes this even stranger, because my problem persists. As @TylerMcEntee noticed, you have a different smtp host. Would that matter? I have no experience with sendgrid.

Comment: If I just change to smtp.sendgrid.net, I get an exception; Failure to send e-mail. But I guess there's more to it. I have updated my question with a screenshot showing the `attachList`.

Comment: you can create a free account on sendgrid.com and use their smtp to send email or any other provider like gmail.com. I have tested you code and it is working fine.

Comment: thanks @PankajKumar, I've done that now, and successfully sent an e-mail using sendgrid, but it's still the same issue, the attachments are copies of the last item in the list.

Comment: @PankajKumar I did manage to get this working when using test Excel files. I see you also use Excel files in your locally populated list. Can you get it working with PDFs?
thanks!

Comment: @OleM I have tried with pdf also and it is working as expected, check this  output(https://i.imgur.com/Z9uKzap.png) . can you try with different pdf files?

Comment: @OleM please try to use any other stream method like Data = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read) or try to use  System.Net.Mail

Comment: @PankajKumar thank you, but I have tried that already, several different methods, but none will work.
I am just very curious as to why this will work for others and not me. I might have to look for an alternative to FluentEmail, but I really would like to figure this out.